# Takagi-Sugeno system using frbs R

Tags: r, rstudio, fuzzy-logic

I've been trying to use the R Statistical software to build a Takagi Sugeno fuzzy system. Using the R package 'frbs' I've managed to set up the most of components of the FIS following the example in the demo files. Unfortunately I've hit a problem:
Error in validate.params(object, newdata) : 
  Please check your num.labels parameters
I've been trying to predict some value, and I don't know what is wrong in this script. When i comment the last line everything seems to be ok, but only one plot is drawing.

```
#  rm(list=ls())  # not generally appreciated
library(frbs)
varinp.mf <- matrix(c( 5, -1, 0.8493, NA, NA, 5, 1, 0.8493, NA, NA,
                       5, -1, 0.8493, NA, NA, 5, 1, 0.8493, NA, NA),
                    nrow = 5, byrow = FALSE)
num.fvalinput <- matrix(c(2,2), nrow=1)
x1 <- c("a1","a2")
x2 <- c("b1","b2")
names.varinput <- c(x1, x2)
range.data <- matrix(c(-1.5,1.5, -1.5, 1.5), nrow=2)
type.defuz <- "5"
type.tnorm <- "MIN"
type.snorm <- "MAX"
type.implication.func <- "MIN"
name <- "Przykład"
newdata <- matrix(c(-0.6, 0.3), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames.var <- c("x1", "x2")
type.model <- "TSK"
func.tsk <- matrix(c(1,   1,  1,
                     2,   1,  0,
                     1,  -2, -1,
                    -1, 0.5, -2),
                   nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

rule <- matrix(c("A1","and","B1","->",  
                 "A1","and","B2","->", 
                 "A2","and","B1","->",  
                 "A2","and","B2","->"),
                 nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
object <- frbs.gen( range.data, num.fvalinput, names.varinput,
                  num.fvaloutput, varout.mf=NULL, names.varoutput, rule,
                 varinp.mf, type.model, type.defuz, type.tnorm, type.snorm,
                  func.tsk, colnames.var, type.implication.func)



plotMF(object)
res <- predict(object, newdata)$predicted.val
```

Comment: Why's this tagged MATLAB?

Comment: I hope someone in MATLAB tag, know what is wrong

Comment: As it's not written in MATLAB, that is not going to work. I have removed the tag.

Comment: @Garbaczyk You can't assume that anyone in the MATLAB tag is also a `R` programmer.  That's like tagging for example a question with both Python and Microsoft VBA... yeah, pairing the two is a bit nonsensical right?  The same goes for here.  You can't tag questions in conflicting languages unless your question specifically deals with both. Your question only deals with `R` only.

Comment: ok it was my mistake, so I will not do things like that in the future

Comment: Using R functions debugging is often assisted when one supplies arguments to function using pairlists with their named parameters. So you might start by not using positional matching of the `object <- frbs.gen( range.data, num.fvalinput, names.varinput, ...` call. You should also post the entire error message and indicate what function throws the error. I edited you question to comment the destructive code at the top. That tends to annoy people when left in.

Comment: This is the error:                        Error in validate.params(object, newdata) : Please check your num.labels parameters. But num.labels isn't  using in this script.

Comment: `num.labels` is an item name in the retruned object from `frbs.gen`

Comment: It seems to be ok. I need to draw 2 MF grade functions, in 2 plots, so values in num.labels need to be 2,2

Answer (score 0):

The test that is failing is seen in the `validate.params` code:

```
frbs:::validate.params
....
else if (object$type.model == c("TSK")) {
    if (ncol(object$num.labels) != (ncol(object$range.data.ori) - 
        1)) {
        stop("Please check your num.labels parameters")
```

When I run the code in the example on the `frbs.gen` help page I then see:

```
> res <- predict(object, newdata)$predicted.val
> object$range.data.ori
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]  100  100  100  100  100
> object$num.labels
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    2    3    3
```

Whereas with you example I see:

```
> object$num.labels
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
> object$range.data.ori
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] -1.5 -1.5
[2,]  1.5  1.5
```

So your 'object'-object was not created according to the package author's expectations. Seems that the error should have been caught earlier in the process, rather than letting it get signaled by `predict.frbs`.

Comment: Ok, i add range data to output and now it seems to be ok. But now i have another problem with prediction. Something is wrong with rule  Error in rule[, (4 * i), drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds